# Autocomplete is not working with cocoon in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete, cocoon-gem

I try to use autocomplete in a form in cocoon but I can not do it, these are my codes

In my form:

```
                <div class="col l6 m6 s12" style="margin-bottom:40px">
              <%= link_to_add_association '<i class="material-icons left" style="font-size:2rem">playlist_add</i>Agregar módulo'.html_safe, f, :modulus, onclick:'count_modulus()' , class: 'btn waves-effect waves-light light-green z-depth-3 button-add_modulu', style:'position: absolute;', data: { association_insertion_node: '.modulu', association_insertion_method: :append } %>
            </div>

            <div id="demo" class="center-align">¿Esta seguro que desea eliminar este modulo?</div>  
            <ul class='col s12 modulu countBody collapsible popout' data-collapsible="accordion" style="padding: 0;">
              <%= f.simple_fields_for :modulus do |builder| %>
                <%= render 'modulu_fields', f: builder %>
              <% end %>
             </ul>
```

In mi nested:

```
<li class="nested-fields">
  <div class="input-field col s12" >
    <i class="material-icons prefix">import_contacts</i>
    <%= f.text_field :description, class: 'autocomplete', data: {autocomplete_source: @hola.map} %>
    <%= f.label :description %>
  </div>
```

In mi js file:

```
  $('.modulu').on('cocoon:after-insert', function(e, added_thing) {
  console.log('hola')
  added_thing.find($('input.autocomplete')).focus(function(){
    $(this).autocomplete({
       minLength: 2,
       source: ["foo","foobar","foobaz"]
        });
});
```

});

it looks like this, in fact it shows up the console.log

[imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f08Mn.jpg)
Help :c

UPDATE:
More simple:

In my form:

```
              <div class="row">
            <div class="col l6 m6 s12" style="margin-bottom:40px">
              <%= link_to_add_association '<i class="material-icons left" style="font-size:2rem">playlist_add</i>Agregar módulo'.html_safe, f, :modulus, onclick:'count_modulus()' , class: 'btn waves-effect waves-light light-green z-depth-3 button-add_modulu', style:'position: absolute;', data: { association_insertion_node: '.modulu', association_insertion_method: :append } %>
            </div>
            <!-- information for complete -->
            <%= content_tag :div, class: "temp_information", data: {autocomplete_source: @programas.map} do %>
            <% end %>
            <!-- form -->
            <div class='col s12 modulu' style="padding: 0;">
              <%= f.simple_fields_for :modulus do |builder| %>
                <%= render 'modulu_fields', f: builder %>
              <% end %>
             </div>
          </div>
```

In my nested:

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <div class="input-field col s12" >
   <!-- this element I need complete -->
   <i class="material-icons prefix">import_contacts</i>
   <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'jojo' %>
   <%= f.label :name %>
 </div>
```

In my js:

```
  // my js 
  $('ul.modulu').on('cocoon:after-insert', function(e, added_thing) {
   console.log('hola');
   $(".jojo").autocomplete({ 
   source: function(request, response) {
  var results = 
   $.ui.autocomplete.filter($('.temp_information').data('temp'), request.term);
  response(results.slice(0, 5));
    }
  });
 });
```

My code in video:
https://youtu.be/dXIkxTD0zbM

Comment: Your question is hard to understand, but I am guessing that is because of the language. Imho your `cocoon:after-insert` can never be triggered, so it will _not_ add `hola` in the console, is that correct? You should attach the event handler to a _surrounding_ element, e.g. like a div or the form itself.

Comment: I insert a video of my code https://youtu.be/dXIkxTD0zbM

Comment: yes, my code shows hola